# Fetching error from different port on localhost

Tags: javascript, http, post, fetch

I'm trying to make `POST` request by fetch function and frontend/backend servers are on different ports.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3035', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'same-origin', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: 'include', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(line), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

but getting an errors:

`Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3030/ may not load data from http://localhost:3035/.`

`TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`

Answer (score 0):

Different ports are treated as different domain.
So you have to declare a CORS policy (on the server side) in order to be able to contact an host from another one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Be aware on the security...
If you declare

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

All the external hosts can contact your endpoint (and if it is exposed to the Internet, it could issue security vulnerabilities)